# how to configure Active admin support for mongoid and active record both?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activeadmin

I develop one application in rails which support mongodb CRUD and postgress CRUD its working with both database.

Now I like to make admin interface which communicate with both database. Mongodb and postgress.

I install below gem

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem "activeadmin-mongoid",  git: "git://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid.git"
```

I configure active admin as describe below

http://activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html#initialize_active_admin

Now my active_admin work with mongodb model but not working with active_recode model

its give me below error

Don't know what context to use for AdminUser

Please help me support both database on active admin

Comment: I asked the same question and was answered that is it not possible to use both adapters at the same time :(. Mongoid support in in progress: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2714

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not officially supported by ActiveAdmin version 1.0.0.pre1. I expect that someone will develop an adapter once ActiveAdmin reaches 1.0.